# JS/Regex: How to set group in a regex for multiple replacement?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I would like to replace a string in another string. My problem is, that the search-string is a variable and I need to set a group for this, because I want to reuse the original matching string.

```
const string = 'Any string with many words'
const label = 'any'
const re = new RegExp(label, 'gi')

string = string.replace(
    re,
    '>>>' + $1 + '<<<'
)

console.log(string)
// Expect: >>>Any<<< string with m>>>any<<< words
```

Comment: Use `'>>>$&<<<'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a backreference inside a *string* replacement pattern. Also, to access the whole match value, you need to use `$&` backreference, not `$1`. The `$1` backreference will work of you use parentheses around the whole pattern (like `` new RegExp(`(${label})`, 'gi') ``), but you do not need that since there is a convenient `$&` backreference. See [**Specifying a string as a parameter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

```js
let string = 'Any string with many words';
const label = 'any';
const re = new RegExp(label, 'gi');

string = string.replace(
    re,
    '>>>$&<<<'
)

console.log(string)
```

Note that `string` should not be declared as `const` if you need to modify its value (I used `let` above).

Note, that if your `label` contains special regex chars, it is a good idea to [escape the `label` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).